# How to clear array which is inside nested state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I have crated state like below and at some point I want to clear this array and update with new one. I used below code for clearing, but when I check state through react-developer tool, array is still there nothing is happening. Please help me as my newbie to ReactJS.

```
state = {
        formData:{
            level:{
                element:'select', 
                value:'Bachelors',
                label:true,
                labelText:'Level',
                config: {
                    name:'department',
                    options: [
                        {val :"Bachelors", text:'Bachelors'},
                        {val:"Masters", text:'Masters'}
                    ]
                },
                validation: {
                    required:false,
                }
                ,
                valid:true,
                touched:false,
                validationText:'',
            },
```

Now I want to clear options array by:

```
let {options} = this.state.formData.level.config
options = []
this.setState({
    options:options
})
```

But my array is not clearing. How can I achive that?

Comment: You are setting a new property called `options` in the state.
You need to use spread operator to copy the existing state and then replace `this.state.formData.level.config.options` with whatever you want to replace it with.

Comment: Hi still-learning-programming, I just provided you a solution. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that you should know.

1) When you do `this.setState({ options: options })`, you are not updating the `options` array belonging to the `formData` object. You are creating a brand new key-value pair in your `state` called `options`. If you try to print your updated state, you will find that your state now looks like:

```
state = { formData: {...}, options: [] }
```

2) You are trying to directly mutate state, (changing a value belonging to the existing object). This is against React principles, because in order for the component to re-render correctly without being prone to side-effects, you need to provide a brand new state object.

Since its so deeply nested, the likely best option is to deep clone your state-object like this:

```
const newFormData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.formData))
newFormData.level.config.options = []

this.setState({
  formData: newFormData 
})
```

This will probably be the safest way to clear your form data object. Here's a working sandbox with this feature as well. Please use it for reference:

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-cache-0ncks

Answer (score 0):

create `newstate` and change `properties`  then apply the new state to `setState()` function like this:

```
 changestate = ()=>{
   var newstate = this.state;
   newstate.formData.level.config.options=["hello","wow"]
   this.setState(newstate)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing the options state but creating a new state with an empty array. 
You can either clone the whole object using JSON stringify and JSON parse too . Other way to update nested states without mutation is by using spread operators. The syntax looks a bit complex though as spread nested objects while preserving everything is tricky.

```
const newFormData = {
   ...this.state.formData,
   level: {
          ...this.state.formData.level,
          config: {
                  ...this.state.formData.level.config,
                  options: []
                  }
          }
};

this.setState({
   formData: newFormData 
})
```